# Automatically subset data in a large list that contains lists which contain dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I am trying to solve a (for me very complex) problem. I will do my best to explain it.

I am working with a list that contains 150 other lists. These sublists contain 3 dataframes each. Here is the `str()` from the list that contains 150 lists that contain the dataframes:

```
str(listSM)

$ SE1  :List of 3
  ..$ d20:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d50:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d5 :'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
 $ SE10 :List of 3
  ..$ d20:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d50:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d5 :'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
 $ SE100:List of 3
  ..$ d20:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d50:'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d5 :'data.frame': 96408 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Date: Date[1:96408], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. ..$ SWC : num [1:96408] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
```

The code above shows only 3 dataframes. These are called SE1, SE2, SE3, SE4, …, all the way up to SE150. Within these lists there are always 3 dataframes with the same name in each list, namely d20, d50 and d5.

Here is what I want to do:

**I want to create multiple subsets for each dataframe (d20, d50, d5) in each list based on the date and store them in a new variable with a unique name.** Each dataframe contains dates from 2009-2019.

I wrote this as an example:

```
        SE1_d20_2009 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date <= "2009-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2010 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2009-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2010-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2011 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2010-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2011-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2012 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2011-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2012-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2013 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2012-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2013-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2014 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2013-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2014-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2015 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2014-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2015-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2016 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2015-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2016-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2017 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2016-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2017-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2018 <- subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2017-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2018-12-31 23:00:00")
        SE1_d20_2019 <-subset(listSM$SE1$d20, Date > "2018-12-31 23:00:00" & Date <= "2019-12-31 23:00:00"
```

As you can see I wanna make yearly subsets. Furthermore, the variable names depend on the **SE** number and the **d** number. This is soil moisture measurement data so **SE** stands for the sensor and **d** for the depth of the sensor.  The code above is an example for the variable names for SE1 and d20, so the names for SE2 should be: SE2_d20_2009, SE2_d20_2010 and so on… But of course I do not just want to do that for d20 but also for d5 and d50, so variable names for these depths would be: SE2_d5_2009, SE2_d5_2010 // SE2_d50_2009, SE2_d50_2010 and so on….

Obviously I could do this for each dataframe within the lists as above, but this is a total of 450 dataframes and this would take far too long. So I wonder if this could be automated and if so, how? Since I am a complete beginner in R this is beyond my competence so I’m really hoping someone can help me. Don't hesitate to ask any questions if this is incomprehensible, I tried my best to explain it.

EDIT:

```
dput(droplevels(listSM$SE1$d20[1:50, ]))

structure(list(Date = structure(c(14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 
14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 
14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14247, 
14247), class = "Date"), SWC = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Storing as unique variables is not a great idea(fills Globalenv). Maybe subset and keep these subsets in a list? Could you make a simple list that we can work with to test some possible solutions?

Comment: @NelsonGon Yeah you're probably right, would be mess with all the variables. I added dput(droplevels() to the post so you can see what one dataframe looks like. All the others look exactly the same but with different values (they're usually not all NaN just in the beginning of the year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
list_df <- lapply(listSM, function(x) 
             lapply(x, function(y) split(y, format(y$Date, "%Y"))))
```

This would return a list of lists as output in `list_df`. It is good to store data in lists as it is easy to manage rather than having lot of objects in global environment.

If you want list with single level instead of lists of list do

```
unlist(list_df, recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That solved it. Can't believe that just 2 lines of code can make that happen. And I was already thinking about using 3 for loops with if statements, haha.